# What operations are O(n) on the number of tables in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql

Let's say theoretically, I have database with an absurd number of tables (100,000+). Would that lead to any sort of performance issues? Provided most queries (99%+) will only run on 2-3 tables at a time.

Therefore, my question is this:

**What operations are O(n) on the number of tables in PostgreSQL?**

Please note, no answers about how this is bad design, or how I need to plan out more about what I am designing. Just assume that for my situation, having a huge number of tables is the best design.

Comment: It's hard to enumerate all cases. Metadata queries like those run by `\dt` will certainly be affected. Operations that check dependencies can also suffer (anything that uses `pg_depend`), and those are all over the place. The performance penalty can be worse than linear; depends on the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pg_dump` and `pg_restore` and `pg_upgrade` are actually worse than that, being O(N^2).  That used to be a huge problem, although in recent versions, the constant on that N^2 has been reduced to so low that for 100,000 table it is probably not enough to be your biggest problem.  However, there are worse cases, like dumping tables can be O(M^2) (maybe M^3, I don't recall the exact details anymore) for each table, where M is the number of columns in the table.  This only applies when the columns have check constraints or defaults or other additional info beyond a name and type.  All of these problems are particularly nasty when you have no operational problems to warn you, but then suddenly discover you can't upgrade within a reasonable time frame.

Some physical backup methods, like `barman` using `rsync`, are also O(N^2) in the number of files, which is at least as great as the number of tables.

During normal operations, the stats collector can be a big bottleneck.  Everytime someone requests updated stats on some table, it has to write out a file covering all tables in that database.  Writing this out is O(N) for the tables in that database.  (It used to be worse, writing out one file for the while instance, not just the database).  This can be made even worse on some filesystems, which when renaming one file over the top of an existing one, implicitly fsyncs the file, so putting it on a RAM disc can at least ameliorate that.

The autovacuum workers loop over every table (roughly once per autovacuum_naptime) to decide if they need to be vacuumed, so a huge number of tables can slow this down.  This can also be worse than O(N), because for each table there is some possibility it will request updated stats on it.  Worse, it could block all concurrent autovacuum workers while doing so (this last part fixed in a backpatch for all supported versions).

Another problem you might into is that each database backend maintains a cache of metadata on each table (or other object) it has accessed during its lifetime.  There is no  mechanism for expiring this cache, so if each connection touches a huge number of tables it will start consuming a lot of memory, and one copy for each backend as it is not shared.  If you have a connection pooler which hold connections open indefinitely, this can really add up as each connection lives long enough to touch many tables.

Answer (score 0):

`pg_dump` with some options, probably `-s`. Some other options make it depend more on size of data.

Comment: So other than the pg_dump command, most operations should still be performant given the conditions?